# Symfony 2 Form collection field with type file

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to upload multiple files with POST request (without Ajax). Can I use Symfony 2's form collection field with type file like this:

Code in Entity:

```php
public $pictures;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->pictures = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

Code in Form Class:

```php
$builder->add('pictures', 'collection', array(
        'type' => 'file',
        'required' => false,
        'attr' => array(
            'multiple' => 'multiple'
        )
));
```

Code in Twig:

```html
{% for picture in form.pictures %}
    <td>
        {{ form_widget(picture) }}
    </td>
{% endfor %}
```

I tried, but it doesn't seem to work. It is not showing any errors, but it is not showing the input file either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

To actually render input types you will need to set the allow_add option in the collection to true and use the form prototype of the collection, javascript and a button to add file fields.

An example based in the documentation ([Collection- adding and removing](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/collection.html#adding-and-removing-items))

The form:

```
<form action="..." method="POST" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
{# ... #}

{# store the prototype on the data-prototype attribute #}
<ul id="image-container" class="collection-container" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.images.vars.prototype) | e }}">
{% for imageField in form.images%}
    <li>
        {{ form_widget(imageField) }}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="#" class="collection-add" data-collection="image-container">Add image</a>

</form>
```

The script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var imageCount;

  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.collection-add', function () {
        var $collectionContainer = $('#' + $(this).data('collection'));
        if(!imageCount){imageCount = $collectionContainer.children().length;}
        var prototype = $collectionContainer.attr('data-prototype');
        var item = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, imageCount);
        $collectionContainer.append(item);
        imageCount++;
    });
  })
</script>
```

This is just an idea, there is still plenty to do depending on your needs.
If this wasn't what you were looking for, maybe you could call the add button click as a workaround.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to show multiple input fields, no, it won't work. A collection type requires you to supply some data before rendering the fields. I've already tried it, and came up creating a separate entity (e.g. File) and and adding relationship to my target entity.

example:

```
class File
{
    // properties

    public $file; // this holds an UploadedFile object

    // getters, setters
}
```

FileType:

```
....

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('file', 'file', [
            'required' => false
        ])
    ;
}
```

Product:

```
class Product
{
    // properties

    private $images; // ManyToMany relationship

    // setters, getters
}
```

ProductType:

```
->add('images', 'collection', [
    'type' => 'YOUR_FILE_TYPE_NAME',
    'by_reference' => false,
    'required' => false
])
```

Product contoller:

```
public function someAction()
{
    ...

    $image = new File();
    $product->addImage($image);

}
```

I know this solution can be overkill and creates extra tables, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the type of the widget in collection

Look at the: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/collection.html

```
$builder->add('pictures', 'collection', array(
  // each item in the array will be an "email" field
  'type'   => 'file',
  // these options are passed to each "email" type
  'options'  => array(
    'required'  => false,
  ),
));
```

For further reading I suggest

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/file.html

Also you need to add sth to this collection to display cuz it will be empty when initialize like in your constructor of entity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it hundred times, but it didn't work.

Comment: This does not create a file selection box where it is possible to select multiple files at once.

Comment: I think you need to use some bundle to handle the multiple upload. Because by default it will create multiple single file uploads.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the form class is correct, but you also should modify the name of the formfield. The `full_name` should be `form[pictures][]` in your case.

It actually seems that modifying a form field name is not possible anymore in sf2.3, but it will be possible in sf2.4 again.

https://github.com/bamarni/symfony/commit/35639824e864ed8d4a4cc0d8360f2c73ae08b507#commitcomment-3627879