# Symfony2 Upload multiple files

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Hello everyone I still learning symfony2 and I want to handle uploading multiple files to server. I try execute 2 entities by one form. 
I have Document, Product entity and

form CreateProductType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', 'text')   //  product name, quantity, description, etc
        ->add('file','file',array(
            'required' => false,
            'mapped' => false,
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Document',
            'attr' => array(
                'accept' => 'image/*',
                'multiple' => 'multiple',
            )
        ));
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class'       => 'AppBundle\Entity\Product'
    ));
}
```

what I supposed to do in controller to put files to uploads folder, insert new product

```
name,description,quantity,price, etc
```

and document (photos)

```
id, path, product_id
```

to database?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT.
my Document entity looks like [this Document.php](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If use form multiple array you should use collection in builder:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('files', 'collection', array(
            'type' => 'file',
            'options'  => array(
                'required' => false,
                'mapped' => false,
                'attr' => array(
                    'accept' => 'image/*',
                    'multiple' => 'multiple',
                )
            )
        ))
        ->add('product', new ProductType())
        ->add('save', 'submit', array(
            'label' => 'Submit',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-default')
        ));
}
```

and then use array collection in entity:

```
/**
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
 */
public $files;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->files = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add file
 *
 * @param UploadedFile $file
 * @return UploadedFile
 */
public function addFile(UploadedFile $file)
{
    $this->files[] = $file;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove file
 *
 * @param UploadedFile $file
 */
public function removeFile(UploadedFile $file)
{
    $this->files->removeElement($file);
}
```

Because multiple upload need has an array name `name="files[]"` to store file multiple.

**SEE:** [Multiple file upload with Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736946/multiple-file-upload-with-symfony2)
and
[Symfony 2 Form collection field with type file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410578/symfony-2-form-collection-field-with-type-file)